# AdvancedTableViewCells and UITabBar

Tags: iphone

Very simple, but maybe difficult to answer question.
How do you include an AdvancedTableViewCells (à la AppStore) inside a tab bar item?

(Just like the App Store Top 25 tab bar item)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You mean being able to add more results ? top 25 => top 50 etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table cells have nothing to do with tab bars, so you're going to have to be more specific.

Regards 
Tariq

Answer (score 0):

don't know if I understood you well but you can include any view inside UITabBarItem just by using method:

```
initWithCustomView:
```

Cheers,
Krzysztof Zabłocki